# 1.9 TDI Skoda Octavia estate with Multiple faults

Tags: clutch, air-intake, skoda, break

[image]
I recently took my Skoda into the main Skoda garage to get some minor issues fixed,
such as the cigarette lighter not working in the front for my satnav,
a flashing orange coil light on the dash[for the past 8 months].
& the front drivers seat locking up occassionally when it is reclined.
As part of the service they done a free health check.
Which resolved in multiple faults being found, around 20 in
total, some of which were a health hazard..

just wondering what these two following faults ment...

```
Clutch needs replacing, which is pretty self explanitory
but it says Jerry operation & excessive free play on pedal.
```

What is a Jerry Operation?
                   &

```
intake pipe post maf split?
```

What does post maf mean?

Also has Active Static Fault with All Four Glowplugs.
Both rear bump stops seperated.
Active static fault with brake pedal Switch..

& multiple other faults which are too expensive to fix.

Anybody Know any good Uk web sites[Norwich] to list it for breaking & spare parts?.
Already listed it on gumtree...

Looking for a Skoda Scout to replace it if anyones got one for sale locally.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. I have no clue what "Jerry Operation" is ... hoping someone else on here might be able to clear that up. The MAF is the Mass Air Flow sensor. It tells the computer how much air is going into the engine, which basically allows it to adjust fuel input to match. With a split in the intake after the MAF, it means you are getting unmetered air into your engine, which will not allow for optimal operation.

Comment: Jerky operation?

Comment: @Phil G No it says Jerry...

Comment: Understood, just trying to guess if it's a typo in the writeup.